# Calculator for metric distance from an expression that contains different scales

Tags: java

```
public enum Operator {
PLUS("+"),
MINUS("-");

private final String operator;

Operator(String operator) {
    this.operator = operator;
}

public String getOperator() {
    return operator;
}

public static Operator getByValue(String operator) {
    for (Operator operatorEnum : Operator.values()) {
        if (operatorEnum.getOperator().equals(operator)) {
            return operatorEnum;
        }
    }

    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid value");
}
}
```

//////////

```
 public enum MetricConvertor {
m(1000),
cm(10),
mm(1),
km(1000000),
dm(100);

private int scale;

MetricConvertor(int scale) {
    this.scale = scale;
}

public int getScale() {
    return scale;
}

}
```

/////////

```
 public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int scale = MetricConvertor.valueOf("m").getScale();
}
```

I wan to create a calculator that is capable of computing a metric distance value from an expression that contains different scales and systems.

Output should be specified by the user.

Only Addition and subtraction is allowed.

Output is in lowest unit.

Expression: 10 cm + 1 m - 10 mm

Result: 1090 mm

I am stuck at this point, how can I add or substract the values for a list and convert them at the lowest scale sistem( eg above mm, but it can be dm if are added for example dm + m + km)

Comment: Have you already implemented a parser for expressions?

Comment: No, this is the whole code that I did

Comment: Break the whole task into smaller components and take it one step at a time. 1. Break the expression into individual objects; 2. Perform the conversion into a common unit (such as mm); 3: Parse the addition/subtraction symbols and evaluate the expression as a whole; 4: Convert to the desired output unit (if necessary) and print the result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution

1. split each string by add/minus and add it to appropriate list
2. split number and metric in each list(can use matcher) and sum it
3. result = sumAdd - sumMinus(mm).
   Please optimize it, because i don't have time to optimize this code, I need to go to bed :D 
   Result is in mm, so you have to get lowest metric and recaculate it(leave it to you).

```
private static int caculator(String exp) {
    List<String> addList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> minusList = new ArrayList<>();
    int checkPoint = 0;
    boolean op = true;//default first value is plus
    // Split string with add/minus
    for (int i = 1; i < exp.length(); i++) {
        String s = exp.substring(i, i + 1);
        if (Operator.PLUS.getOperator().equals(s)) {
            checkOperator(addList, minusList, op, exp.substring(checkPoint, i).trim());
            checkPoint = i + 1;
            op = true;
            continue;
        }
        if (Operator.MINUS.getOperator().equals(s)) {
            checkOperator(addList, minusList, op, exp.substring(checkPoint, i).trim());
            checkPoint = i + 1;
            op = false;
            continue;
        }
    }
    // Add last string
    checkOperator(addList, minusList, op, exp.substring(checkPoint).trim());
    // Get sum each list
    int sumAdd = sumList(addList);
    int sumMinus = sumList(minusList);

    return sumAdd - sumMinus;
}
//sum a list
private static int sumList(List<String> addList) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (String s: addList) {
        String[] arr = s.split(" ");
        int value = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
        int scale = MetricConvertor.valueOf(arr[1]).getScale();
        sum += value * scale;
    }
    return sum;
}
// check operator to put into approriate list
private static void checkOperator(List<String> addList, List<String> minusList, boolean op, String substring) {
    if (op) {
        addList.add(substring);
    } else {
        minusList.add(substring);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer would be much better if you'd explain the code, the reasoning behind it, and why it works the way it should. That way people don't just copy & paste some code they don't understand from the interwebs, but can actually learn from your answer. :-)